# Transposing Row Data as Columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have the following data returned from a stored procedure

```
Staff  Category   Amount
-----  -------    ------
Bob    Art        123
Bob    Sport      777
Bob    Music      342 
Jeff   Art        0
Jeff   Sport      11
Jeff   Music      27
```

All Categories will always be returned for all Staff even is the Amount is zero

What I want to do on my Crystal Report is output this:-

```
Staff   Art     Sport   Music   
-----   ---     -----   -----   
Bob     123     777     342
Jeff    0       11      27
```

I effectively want to Transpose the data in the Category rows as headers or columns in my report.

I do not want to use a Cross Tab as I have other things I need to add which will not fit nicely into a Cross Tab

Any thoughts on how I can do this in Crystal?  I'm using version 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the report by staff and place staff, Art, Sport, Music as text fields in Group header.

now in details section place data as

```
Staff, formula 1 (If Category='Art' then Amount), formula 2 (If Category='Sport' then Amount), formula 3 (If Category='Music' then Amount)
```

If Staff has only one value then its ok else place Staff in Group footer and take sum of all values in group footer (Don't remove Formula 1,2,3 from details)

Comment: If I put the Category in the Detail section it will simply put each Category on a row, not use the Categories as columns

Comment: This will work with two additions: 1. Instead of putting it in the Details section you'll have to put it in the Group Footer. 2. Instead of placing the amount fields directly in the section, you'll need to insert a summary of those fields, such as a `maximum()`

Comment: So, just so I'm clear, what you are saying is:-  1. Group report by staff 2. Put staff field and Category field as is in the footer and put a summary field max(amount) in the footer as well?

Comment: @David appologize for incomplete answer please see my edited answer use it if it is helpful. Though I didn't test locally I am sure this will work

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks. Interestingly, just like with the pivot example I need a field in my report for every Category I have so if Categories change (unlikely) then I need to modify the report accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to achive this in your sproc with a PIVOT Table. A helpfile on PIVOT tables can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for this.  Thanks, Quite useful.  I can definitely see a use for it.  Although that leaves me placing about 20 additional fields on my report as there are about 20 categories