# how to implement transpose row to column in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

how to  implement  transpose row to column in crystal report using C#
and this Question Not Pivot data

[image]

transpose to

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transposing Row Data as Columns in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826841/transposing-row-data-as-columns-in-crystal-reports)

Comment: @R.McMillan this Question Not Pivot data  Please verify Question