# Crystal Report Data Format Change

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have data like

```
Date         ColumnName1 ColumnName2  ColumnName3  ColumnName4  ColumnName5

2018-04-01       1            2           3            4            5
2018-04-02       6            7           8            9            10
2018-04-03       11           12          13           14           15
2018-04-04       16           17          18           19           20
2018-04-05       21           22          23           24           25
```

and I want data like following

```
2018-04-01     2018-04-02     2018-04-03    2018-04-03     2018-04-05 
         1              6             11            16             21
         2              7             12            17             22
         3              8             13            18             23
         4              9             14            19             24
         5             10             15            20             25
```

Now what to do?

Comment: I have an idea that might work, but before we go down that rabbit hole check out this link and see if it helps you at all.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826841/transposing-row-data-as-columns-in-crystal-reports]

Comment: Not working .........